# Creating a secondary DNS zone on a newly trusted forrest

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I'm at a loss figured I'd ask here..

The company I work for recently bought out another Cardiology group. We've setup a site to site link (100 Mbps fiber dedicated) and I was in the process of setting up a trust for the two domains while I build the new domain infrastructure.

Current setup:

2 domains both Server 2003 x64 R2
Each domain has 3 DC's.

Domain one (call it CVI) I was able to create a secondary dns zone on based off of the Primary zone over at Domain two. (Call it GAC)

However, when I try to reverse it and go the other way, create a secondary DNS zone over at GAC for CVI, it fails.. always.

1. Both networks can ping and transfer data to each other.
2. Zone transfers are allowed on both ends, I've tried both to named servers and even tried to ANY server to troubleshoot.
3. I have full DA rights on both Domains.

I'm at a loss. Both creating a secondary zone, and creating a stub fail on the GAC domain from the CVI domain.

Any help at this point would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to configure an External/Forest trust you should try setting up a conditional forwarder on each DNS server. This will reduce the replication traffic that will occur with zone transfers and requests to each domain will be forwarded to the appropriate DNS server